# ADK with Google Nexus 4

Tags: android, arduino, adk, nexus-4

I'm trying to get my mega ADK to work with a Google Nexus 4 device (by LG) and having little to no luck with it. Not even the demo app from play store. Has anyone been able to get this phone going with the ADK? or does anyone know if this device has accessory mode support? 
I only see people getting the Nexus S to work but nothing about the Nexus 4.
Some of the links I find are starting to make me think otherwise
http://www.androidcentral.com/google-edits-nexus-4-online-help-manual-removes-reference-usb-gadget-support
but no way to confirm. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: I just tried with my Nexus 4/ADK 2012. Bluetooth worked fine. When I plugged into USB, it looked like it would work but the phone seemed to get stuck in a connecting/disconnecting loop with the ADK.

Comment: @majormajors Thanks a lot for trying it out. Yea the USB connection is of more interest to me. I assume that over bluetooth we do not have access to ADK features is that right? Also, did you use a bluetooth dongle on the USB-A port on the mega ADK?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I'm trying with the ADK released at I/O last year. It sounds to me like you're using the older ADK platform from 2011. The one I have has bluetooth built in, so there's no need for a dongle. I'm afraid I can't help you with the older version since I don't own one.

Comment: @majormajors. Thanks anyways for trying. Lucky you got hold of the google board

Comment: Just an update to anyone who is trying the same. I was able to get Nexus 4 working with ADK as an accessory. The ArduinoBlinkLED example in the usb host shield 2.0 helped. But I wasnt able to get Nexus 4 to work as a usb host with OTGs. Looks like the device not support the mode https://plus.google.com/103927737127033874000/posts/GYdArAVV9nb

Comment: Can you tell me how you got this working? I'm trying a stock (Verizon, if it matters) Nexus 4 connecting with an accessory, but the protocol returns 0 (meaning not supported). Was there some trick you did to get this working? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From   http://source.android.com/tech/accessories/aoap/aoa2.html#detecting, I had to:

1. change protocol test from ==1 to >=1 in switchDevice

   if (protocol >= 1)
2. check for these additional device modes:

   0x2D04 - accessory + audio

   0x2D05 - accessory + audio + adb

and I had to make sure I had enough power (discussion of USB power issues here: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobile/xQhUljmWY5E)